# convert Kodak png images into webP with sampling factor

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, image-compression, webp

I am trying to convert png images into webP with sampling factor. I am imagemagick tool for conversion, as they mentioned in docs -quality is used for sampling but it did not work.

This command works fine to covert kodak png to JPEG.

```
convert test/images/kodim$i.png -quality $(($j*5)) -sampling-factor 4:2:0 test/jpeg/kodim$i/`printf "%02d" $j`.jpg
```

Converting PnG to WebP

```
convert test/images/kodim$i.png -quality $(($j*5)) test/webP/kodim$i/`printf "%02d" $j`.webp
```

I want to follow same sampling as mentioned in JPEG.

Comment: Where did you find information in the docs about using `-quality` for `webp` please? There doesn't appear to be any mention of chroma-subsampling in the complete list of `webp` defines... https://imagemagick.org/script/webp.php

Comment: I mean that i want to chroma sampling for fair comparison

Answer (score 0):

This work fine on kodak images.

Just install webP encoder

```
sudo apt-get install webp
```

Code

```
 for i in {01..24..1}; do
      echo WebP Encoding test/images/kodim$i.png
      mkdir -p test/webP/kodim$i
      for j in {0..20..1}; do
        cwebp test/images/kodim$i.png -q $(($j*5)) -o test/webP/kodim$i/`printf "%02d" $j`.webp
      done
    done
```

**Important**

This command creates a WebP lossy image at different qualities.
WebP lossy is always with YUV420 sampling, equivalent to imagemagick's -sampling-factor 2x2 (also -sampling-factor 4:2:0) for jpeg.